# Add scrollView in DrawerLayout having NavigationView and Toolbar

Tags: android, scrollview, navigation-drawer

I want to create home page for my application. I want to have scrollview in the layout of the homepage. I tried adding scrollview inside DrawerLayout, but nothing helped. I kept the scrollview at various placed in DrawerLayout, but its not working. How do we do that?

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!--Main content-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

        <ScrollView>
             Other layouts and views here!
             But it is not working!
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Navigation Drawer-->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"

        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

What I get is [image]

What I want is scroll view with all other functionalities intact. Some what like. [image]

Comment: Im sorry But i wasnt able to understand your question?

Comment: Please check now..

Comment: ScrollView must have a layout (Linear, Relative,...) inside of it with wrap_content as layout_height. Did you do that?